# Eclipse refactor (rename) doesn't work anymore

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I don't know what happened to my Eclipse, but lately I can't get refactor to work.

I rename a method or a field using the refactor tool, it seem to try to refactor; I also can see that the according name changes ok in the same file I'm working on, **but then when it's done computing the change, it turns the name back to what it was!** I don't know why.

Tried to google it, didn't find any answer relevant to my case, has anyone experienced it? Does anyone know how to fix this?

I suspect it has something to do with the SVN plugin; could it?

Comment: Refactoring in what language?

Comment: @nitind java language